# Travis unable to find csharp solution

Tags: c#, nunit, travis-ci

In reference to [this](https://travis-ci.org/chris-brown/OrderedJobsKata/builds/112484897) build and my [./.travis.yml](https://github.com/chris-brown/OrderedJobsKata/blob/master/.travis.yml) file. Im unable to build my project using Travis CI. I get the following error:

`No solution or script defined, exiting`

Going by [csharp.rb:88](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build/blob/db4854ac7f23e31e396af6ef5904e524c1372a63/lib/travis/build/script/csharp.rb#L88), it suggests the solution isnt set in my yml file, but it quite clearly is. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
language: csharp
solution: OrderedJobs.sln
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get install nunit-console
before_script:
  - nuget restore OrderedJobs.sln
after_script:
  - nunit-console OrderedJobs.Tests/bin/Release/OrderedJobs.Tests.dll
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out this was a file format issue. For anyone who comes across this issue. Please make sure your `.travis.yml` file is saved as UTF-8. Further details can be found [here](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/5818).

Comment: To be a bit more specific, UTF-8 without BOM, which was messing it up in my case.