# "No solution or script defined, exiting" during Travis-ci build

Tags: c#, github, .net-core, travis-ci

I am attempting to get Travis-CI working with a dotnet core application using the following `.travis.yml` configuration.

```
language: csharp
sudo: required
dist: trusty
solution: Vigil.sln
mono: none
dotnet: 1.0.0-rc4-004771
```

The message at the end of the build is "No solution or script defined, exiting". I have already [checked the encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689942/travis-unable-to-find-csharp-solution) of the config file.

This is an output of a recent build.

```
Installing .NET Core
$ export DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE=1
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.wfNmoPVNlA --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/apt.postgresql.org.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 417A0893
gpg: requesting key 417A0893 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 417A0893: public key "MS Open Tech <interop@microsoft.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
Selecting previously unselected package libllvm3.6:amd64.
(Reading database ... 88286 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libllvm3.6_1%3a3.6-2ubuntu1~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libllvm3.6:amd64 (1:3.6-2ubuntu1~trusty1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblldb-3.6.
Preparing to unpack .../liblldb-3.6_1%3a3.6-2ubuntu1~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking liblldb-3.6 (1:3.6-2ubuntu1~trusty1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libunwind8.
Preparing to unpack .../libunwind8_1.1-2.2ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libunwind8 (1.1-2.2ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liburcu1.
Preparing to unpack .../liburcu1_0.7.12-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking liburcu1 (0.7.12-0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblttng-ust-ctl2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../liblttng-ust-ctl2_2.4.0-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking liblttng-ust-ctl2:amd64 (2.4.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblttng-ust0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../liblttng-ust0_2.4.0-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking liblttng-ust0:amd64 (2.4.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dotnet-host.
Preparing to unpack .../dotnet-host_1.1.0-preview1-001100-00-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dotnet-host (1.1.0-preview1-001100-00-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dotnet-hostfxr-1.0.1.
Preparing to unpack .../dotnet-hostfxr-1.0.1_1.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dotnet-hostfxr-1.0.1 (1.0.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dotnet-sharedframework-microsoft.netcore.app-1.0.3.
Preparing to unpack .../dotnet-sharedframework-microsoft.netcore.app-1.0.3_1.0.3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dotnet-sharedframework-microsoft.netcore.app-1.0.3 (1.0.3-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dotnet-hostfxr-1.1.0.
Preparing to unpack .../dotnet-hostfxr-1.1.0_1.1.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dotnet-hostfxr-1.1.0 (1.1.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dotnet-sharedframework-microsoft.netcore.app-1.1.0.
Preparing to unpack .../dotnet-sharedframework-microsoft.netcore.app-1.1.0_1.1.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dotnet-sharedframework-microsoft.netcore.app-1.1.0 (1.1.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dotnet-dev-1.0.0-rc4-004771.
Preparing to unpack .../dotnet-dev-1.0.0-rc4-004771_1.0.0-rc4-004771-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dotnet-dev-1.0.0-rc4-004771 (1.0.0-rc4-004771-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libllvm3.6:amd64 (1:3.6-2ubuntu1~trusty1) ...
Setting up liblldb-3.6 (1:3.6-2ubuntu1~trusty1) ...
Setting up libunwind8 (1.1-2.2ubuntu3) ...
Setting up liburcu1 (0.7.12-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up liblttng-ust-ctl2:amd64 (2.4.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up liblttng-ust0:amd64 (2.4.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up dotnet-host (1.1.0-preview1-001100-00-1) ...
Setting up dotnet-hostfxr-1.0.1 (1.0.1-1) ...
Setting up dotnet-sharedframework-microsoft.netcore.app-1.0.3 (1.0.3-1) ...
Setting up dotnet-hostfxr-1.1.0 (1.1.0-1) ...
Setting up dotnet-sharedframework-microsoft.netcore.app-1.1.0 (1.1.0-1) ...
Setting up dotnet-dev-1.0.0-rc4-004771 (1.0.0-rc4-004771-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.9) ...
git.checkout
$ git clone --depth=50 https://github.com/drovani/Vigil.git drovani/Vigil
Cloning into 'drovani/Vigil'...
remote: Counting objects: 721, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (250/250), done.
remote: Total 721 (delta 473), reused 684 (delta 443), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (721/721), 232.41 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (473/473), done.
$ cd drovani/Vigil
$ git fetch origin +refs/pull/5/merge:
remote: Counting objects: 48, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (34/34), done.
remote: Total 48 (delta 27), reused 33 (delta 13), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (48/48), done.
From https://github.com/drovani/Vigil
 * branch            refs/pull/5/merge -> FETCH_HEAD
$ git checkout -qf FETCH_HEAD
$ export TRAVIS_SOLUTION=Vigil.sln
$ dotnet --info
.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-rc4-004771)
Product Information:
 Version:            1.0.0-rc4-004771
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  4228198f0e
Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  14.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.14.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.0-rc4-004771
No solution or script defined, exiting
```

Builds are here: https://travis-ci.org/drovani/Vigil

Source code is here: https://github.com/drovani/Vigil/tree/travis

What am I missing? It seems that everything should be working. The build brings in the correct version of `dotnet`, which should be looking for `.csproj` files. Does Travis-CI not currently fully support the dotnet cli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [this issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6640) .net core does not have a default script to execute, so you need to define one yourself in your `.travis.yml`.

Another example available in https://andrewlock.net/adding-travis-ci-to-a-net-core-app/.